# Custom Selectable Checkboxes To Display Results In Text Box

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a simple Checkbox menu, that will display all selected values when displayed.

test1.php

```
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="#Example1," />1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="#Example2," />2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="#Example3," />3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="#Example4," />4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="#Example5," />5<br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST)
?>
```

After submitting it is received as...

```
Array ( [#Example1] => on [#Example2] => on [formSubmit] => Submit )
```

I would want it to be displayed as...

```
#Example1, #Example2,
```

There needs to be a comma between each result, which is why they all have a comma at the end.

Comment: Change to `name="formDoor`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="#Example1" />1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="#Example2" />2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="#Example3" />3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="#Example4" />4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="#Example5" />5<br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Remove the commas from your values and do this in PHP.

```
$val = implode(",",$_POST["formDoor"]);

echo $val;
```

Comment: I updated my code, and I don't think this would help me, at least all I'm getting from it is errors, how would you modify to work with it as it is now?

Comment: Where are you getting `on` from?

Comment: Not sure. The formDoor was default text that I forgot to remove, so that isn't necessary.